# Tabletop query causing XHR with a Google Sheet

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, tabletop.js

I have two pieces of code that, to me, look exactly the same, except that they point to two different Google Sheets. They both run a query on a Google Sheet using Tabletop.js. Yet the first one gets an XHR error and the second one doesn't. And here's the really weird part, if I comment out the query in the Tabletop code in the non-working code, then the data from the Google Sheet loads into the page without an error. It seems to be the query that is hanging it up. So I can get a list all of the rows but once I query the sheet, no data and an XHR error.

Anyone got any ideas as to why this would be happening?

```
//Pull the Activity Name data. Activity Name is in the query string

$(document).ready(function(){
// if activity name are not passed as parameters, exit function
if (location.search.indexOf('activityname') == -1 || $(".activity-result").length == 0)
{
    return;
}
var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/a/organisationname.org/spreadsheets/d/sheet_id_number/pubhtml';

// Extracting the name from the URL query string
    var toActivityName = location.search.slice(14);
    var spacedActivityName = toActivityName.split('+').join(' ');





                 Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                 callback: showInfo,
                 simpleSheet: true,
                 query: "activity_name = " + spacedActivityName,
                 })


function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

    var template = $.templates("#activityTmpl");
    var htmlOutput = template.render(data);
    $(".activity-result").html(htmlOutput);
```

The code above is the non-working one

This is the working one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// if firstname and surname are not passed as parameters, exit function
if (location.search.indexOf('firstname') == -1 || location.search.indexOf('surname') == -1 || $(".client-result").length == 0)
{
    return;
}
var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/a/organisationname.org/spreadsheets/d/sheet_id_number/pubhtml';

// Extracting the name from the URL query string
var toFirstName = location.search.slice(11);
var whereIsAmpersand = toFirstName.indexOf('&');
var clientFirstName = toFirstName.slice(0,whereIsAmpersand);
var whereIsEqual = toFirstName.indexOf('=');
var clientSurname = toFirstName.slice(whereIsEqual + 1);


Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                 callback: showInfo,
                 simpleSheet: true,
                 query: "firstname = " + clientFirstName + " and surname = " + " " + clientSurname,
                 })

function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

    var template = $.templates("#clientTmpl");
    var htmlOutput = template.render(data);
    $(".client-result").html(htmlOutput);        

    }
});
```

The error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/the_sheet_id_number/public/basic?alt=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.organisationname.org' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It was underscores in the headings of the Google Sheet that wasn't working. Tabletop apparently doesn't like underscores.